# Can I connect a virtual machine to an adhoc network hosted on the host machine?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have created an adhoc network on my laptop, to this network i can connect other computers but the virtual machine won't connect to it and i don't know why, I can't ping the guest machines from the host machine when I'm only using the ad-hoc network, even though i can ping other external physical computers connected to this ad-hoc network.

However if I connect my machine to a router then the virtual machine connects properly and I can ping the host machine from it or the guest machine from the host one. Virtual machine is set on Bridged network adapter mode (Not NAT).

I suspect that I need to virtualize a router for the adhoc network so that I can connect the Virtual Machine to it, but honestly I don't know if that's even possible, help?

I'm using Vmware Workstation if that matters, **my goal is to** connect external virtual machines and local virtual machines to the same network, without the use of a physical router and without the use of cables, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_configure_ws.html) at VMWare support site says:

> By default, the VMnet0 virtual network is set up in bridged mode and bridges to one of the active Ethernet adapters on the host computer.
>   The choice of which adapter it uses is arbitrary. You can restrict the range of choices using options on the Automatic Bridging tab.

Thus, you need to pick your `wlan` adapter as the hosts counterpart of a bridge (see "Configuring Bridged Networking Options on a Windows Host" in that article)